# What's the difference between "callback(value)" and "callback.invoke(value)"?

Tags: android, kotlin, callback

I am trying to use some callbacks in my app, and it works with both **"callback(value)"** and **"callback.invoke(value)"** for the callback to be invoked correctly.

I was wondering if the "callback(value)" is just a shortened version, or **is there a difference between these two ways of invoking a callback?**

My function with both *callback* parameters (but only 1 is needed and works without the other):

```
    fun signIn(username: String, password: String,  callback: (Response?) -> Unit) {

    val reqBody =
        "{\"what_to_do\":\"sign_user_in\",\"username\":\"$username\",\"password\":\"$password\"}"

    val request = createRequest(reqBody)

    myHttpClient.newCall(request).enqueue(object : Callback {
        override fun onResponse(call: Call, response: Response) {
                callback(response)
                callback.invoke(response)
            }
        }

        override fun onFailure(call: Call, e: IOException) {
            // Failed request..
        }
    })
}
```

Comment: I'm not using Kotlin so I suppose there are equivalent in your example. Invoke (by logic) is useful when you want to call Callback passing arguments to it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[`invoke`](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/operator-overloading.html#invoke-operator) is the name of the `operator` function in Kotlin that corresponds to the function call `()` operator. There is no difference between using its operator form `()` or its longer function form `invoke()`. You can even convert between the two with IDE intention actions.